# Attaching an entity of type 'X' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

ErrorMessage :

> Attaching an entity of type 'FaridCRMData.Models.Customer' failed
>   because another entity of the same type already has the same primary
>   key value.
>   This can happen when using the `Attach()` method or setting the state of an 
>   entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting > key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received 
>   database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' 
>   entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 
>   'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

My Code:

```
public class FactorController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult SaveFactor(Factor factor,int id)
    {
        if (id > 0)
        {
            bool result = new FactorService.BaseService.Update(factor);
            return new JsonResult() { Data = result };
        }

    }
}
```

FactorService.BaseService.cs :

```
public bool Update(TEntity entity)
{
    var entry = context.Entry(entity);
    if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached || entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
    {

        context.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);// Error Is Here
        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The issue is that the object already exists in the context with that Id.  You don't need to **Attach** it if it is already there.

Answer (score 21):

I believe you might have invoked Select before the update, By default, DBContext will cache the record when they are fethced (Selected), use "AsNoTracking()" in your select call while fetching record.

Comment: This is the most appropriate answer.

Comment: This is the answer I've been looking for all day! Here is my example, in case it helps someone else figure out where it should go.
Ex: 
`var recordToUpdate = db.Reservations.AsNoTracking().Single(x => x.ID == reservation.ID);` the next few lines are the values in the record that I did not want to update on the edit page, then the `db.Entry(reservation).State = EntityState.Modified;` and `db.SaveChanges();`

Answer (score 6):

have you tried to mark your entity as modified BEFORE attach it to the context?

like this:

```
public bool Update(TEntity entity)
{
    var entry = context.Entry(entity);
    if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached || entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
    {
        entry.State = EntityState.Modified; //do it here

        context.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity); //attach

        context.SaveChanges(); //save it
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: hapy help you!!..the mistery of EF ;-)

Comment: Well, if the first statement (`entry.State = EntityState.Modified`) succeeds, after that the entry is attached. How would EF set the state of an unattached entry? And why `|| entry.State == EntityState.Modified`? What's the point of setting a `Modified` entity to `Modified`? In other words, *only* setting the entry's state to `Modified` is enough. It's more useful to check if the entry isn't `Deleted`.

Comment: For some reason I needed to move the `State=EntityState.Modified` to the beginning of the function, before I actually modified anything. If it was at the end near SaveChanges, it would crash everytime.

Answer (score 2):

If you are selecting some data in between Update operation (as i was getting problem).
Don't use **.ToList()** or **.Find()** .... Instead of that use **as IQueryable** , then use .**AsNoTracking()**..... Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to detach the local version first and then do the update process

```
var localEntity = dbContext.Set<theModel>()
    .Local
    .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == theModel.Id);
if (localEntity != null)
{
    dbContext.Entry(localEntity).State = EntityState.Detached;
}
dbContext.Entry(appModel).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simple  change state for entity wich you trying update and `SaveChanges()`

```
public bool Update(TEntity entity)
{

        context.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
}
```