# EF 6 Insert,Update and delete with generic method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I created web service asp API width EF 6 to connect sql server .. and I created generic method to execute Insert & Update & Delete .. the method is

```
    protected enum ExecuteActions
    {
        Insert,
        Update,
        Delete
    }
protected ResponseResult Execute<T>(T entity,ExecuteActions exAction) where T:class
{
      var model = db.Set<T>();
      switch (exAction)
                {
                    case ExecuteActions.Insert:
                        model.Add(entity);
                        break;
                    case ExecuteActions.Update:
                        model.Attach(entity);
                        db.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                        break;
                    case ExecuteActions.Delete:
                        model.Attach(entity);
                        db.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
                  db.SaveChanges();    
}
```

The Insert is working fine, but the problem is in the Update case .. the incomprehensible thing that is working with some entities and some others throws error

> Attaching an entity of type 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

I found some solutions that explains that I have to use (Find) to get the entity than update it .. but its not compatible with my work .. because I don't know the ID of the generic type in the method.

and I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41376161/attaching-an-entity-of-type-x-failed-because-another-entity-of-the-same-type-a) too

In another project it works by something like this method .. so I thought the problem with entity framework element (edmx) .. so I deleted it and recreated it but nothing happened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an interface for your entity types such as:

```
public interface IKeyed{
     int KeyValue{get;}
}
```

Then have your entities implement the interface such as:

```
public partial class Foo : IKeyed{
     public int KeyValue {get {return this.Id;}}
     public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

And then update your Generic method signature to define T as IKeyed

```
protected ResponseResult Execute<T>(T entity,ExecuteActions exAction) 
                                    where T : class, IKeyed
```

And then reference

```
entity.KeyValue
```

when using the Entity Framework's "Find" method.